# Nginx send all POST data to /dev/null

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to find the most effective way of redirecting all POST data to /dev/null. The goal is to have a way of sending huge amounts of data to the internet, to monitor network performance, but all data should be discarded immediately by the server.

I tried the solution offered by https://devnull-as-a-service.com/code/, but the issue I'm having is that nginx returns without waiting on all POST data to be received, which doesn't create the network traffic I'm hoping to see.

Any ideas, nginx gurus?